# Decoding nested JSON swift

Tags: json, swift

I need to get into **logo** - **original** - **url.** Having issues getting the syntax correct. here is the JSON. Im sure it is a small syntax error but help would be appreciated thanks. I think the issue is where i am created the struct for Logo - i feel like the "original" should be a dictionary, but i am getting an error when i do it both ways.

```
   {
    "pagination": {
        "page_number": 1, 
        "page_size": 50, 
        "continuation": "eyJwYWdlIjogMn0", 
        "has_more_items": true
    }, 
    "events": [
        {
            "name": {
                "text": "Atelier femmes entrepreneurs : Comprendre les leviers de la r\u00e9ussite", 
                "html": "Atelier femmes entrepreneurs : Comprendre les leviers de la r\u00e9ussite"
            }, 
            "description": {
                "text": "Matthieu Jardin offre aux femmes entrepreneurs un atelier d\u00e9velopper votre chiffre d\u2019affaires d\u2019une demi-journ\u00e9e.\nL\u2019atelier permet de d\u00e9couvrir des techniques marketing et commercial pour atteindre 150 000 \u20ac de chiffre d'affaire en 12 mois en ind\u00e9pendant (ou vous permettre de doubler ce chiffre d\u2019affaires si vous l\u2019avez d\u00e9j\u00e0 atteint).\nDepuis 10 ans, nous avons rencontr\u00e9 10 000 entrepreneurs permettant de comprendre les leviers de r\u00e9ussite d\u2019une activit\u00e9 professionnelle dans tous les domaines (sant\u00e9, beaut\u00e9, bien-\u00eatre, mieux-\u00eatre, m\u00e9decine douce, d\u00e9veloppement personnel, coaching, esth\u00e9tique, minceur, marketing, webmarketing, commercial, conseils, services, informatique, photographie, \u00e9dition, \u2026)Venez d\u00e9couvrir nos m\u00e9thodes \u00e0 succ\u00e8s, issue d\u2019une r\u00e9ussite manifeste puis\u00e9e au c\u0153ur de notre exp\u00e9rience.Sortez du lot mat\u00e9rialisez vos r\u00eaves et vibrez votre chiffre d\u2019affaires.", 
                "html": "<P>Matthieu Jardin offre aux <STRONG>femmes entrepreneurs<\/STRONG> un atelier d\u00e9velopper votre chiffre d\u2019affaires d\u2019une demi-journ\u00e9e.<\/P>\n<P>L\u2019atelier permet de d\u00e9couvrir des techniques marketing et commercial pour <STRONG>atteindre 150 000 \u20ac de chiffre d'affaire en 12 mois en ind\u00e9pendant<\/STRONG> (ou vous permettre de doubler ce chiffre d\u2019affaires si vous l\u2019avez d\u00e9j\u00e0 atteint).<\/P>\n<P><BR>Depuis 10 ans, nous avons rencontr\u00e9 <STRONG>10 000 entrepreneurs<\/STRONG> permettant de comprendre les leviers de r\u00e9ussite d\u2019une activit\u00e9 professionnelle dans tous les domaines (sant\u00e9, beaut\u00e9, bien-\u00eatre, mieux-\u00eatre, m\u00e9decine douce, d\u00e9veloppement personnel, coaching, esth\u00e9tique, minceur, marketing, webmarketing, commercial, conseils, services, informatique, photographie, \u00e9dition, \u2026)<BR><BR>Venez d\u00e9couvrir nos m\u00e9thodes \u00e0 succ\u00e8s, issue d\u2019une r\u00e9ussite manifeste puis\u00e9e au c\u0153ur de notre exp\u00e9rience.<BR><BR>Sortez du lot mat\u00e9rialisez vos r\u00eaves et <STRONG>vibrez votre chiffre d\u2019affaires.<\/STRONG><\/P>"
            }, 
            "id": "45831548395", 
            "url": "https://www.eventbrite.fr/e/billets-atelier-femmes-entrepreneurs-comprendre-les-leviers-de-la-reussite-45831548395", 
            "start": {
                "timezone": "Europe/Paris", 
                "local": "2018-12-20T10:00:00", 
                "utc": "2018-12-20T09:00:00Z"
            }, 
            "end": {
                "timezone": "Europe/Paris", 
                "local": "2018-12-20T12:00:00", 
                "utc": "2018-12-20T11:00:00Z"
            }, 
            "organization_id": "216426671512", 
            "created": "2018-05-05T21:03:44Z", 
            "changed": "2018-05-05T21:03:44Z", 
            "capacity": 500, 
            "capacity_is_custom": false, 
            "status": "live", 
            "currency": "EUR", 
            "listed": true, 
            "shareable": true, 
            "online_event": false, 
            "tx_time_limit": 480, 
            "hide_start_date": false, 
            "hide_end_date": false, 
            "locale": "fr_FR", 
            "is_locked": false, 
            "privacy_setting": "unlocked", 
            "is_series": true, 
            "is_series_parent": false, 
            "is_reserved_seating": false, 
            "show_pick_a_seat": false, 
            "show_seatmap_thumbnail": false, 
            "show_colors_in_seatmap_thumbnail": false, 
            "source": "create_2.0", 
            "is_free": true, 
            "version": "3.0.0", 
            "logo_id": "32865078", 
            "organizer_id": "14456692393", 
            "venue_id": "20195991", 
            "category_id": "101", 
            "subcategory_id": null, 
            "format_id": "9", 
            "resource_uri": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/45831548395/", 
            "series_id": "35835727626", 
            "logo": {
                "crop_mask": {
                    "top_left": {
                        "x": 0, 
                        "y": 0
                    }, 
                    "width": 2160, 
                    "height": 1080
                }, 
                "original": {
                    "url": "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F32865078%2F216426671512%2F1%2Foriginal.jpg?auto=compress&s=90b9b081469d121ff3b446365c02865b", 
                    "width": 2160, 
                    "height": 1080
                }, 
                "id": "32865078", 
                "url": "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F32865078%2F216426671512%2F1%2Foriginal.jpg?h=200&w=450&auto=compress&rect=0%2C0%2C2160%2C1080&s=9989b1febf7b1317555501973300a8f1", 
                "aspect_ratio": "2", 
                "edge_color": null, 
                "edge_color_set": true
            }
        },
```

Here is my Decodable code

```
struct Eventbrite: Decodable {
    let events: [Event]

}

struct Event: Decodable {
    let name: Name
    let description: Description
    let start: Start
    let logo: Logo
}

struct Name : Decodable {
    let text, html : String
}

struct Description : Decodable {
    let text : String?
}

struct Start : Decodable {
    let timezone, local, utc : String

}

struct Logo: Decodable{
    let original: String?
}

struct Original: Decodable{
    let url: String?
}
```

Comment: The JSON is not valid, at the end of the `text` line in the `description` dictionary  a double quote is missing. Yes, `original` is a dictionary which is represented by a struct. It's the same pattern as the other dictionary / struct relationships. Hint: `original` is not `String` (and it's not optional).

Comment: Sorry- I actually edited and cut some of the in between JSON because it was like another 20 lines until the line I needed to decode came. So please excuse any of that

Comment: With the given incomplete and corrupted JSON nobody can quickly check the code in a Playground.

Comment: WOW! I had no clue! - i just updated the corrupted JSON now.. rookie mistake! apologies everybody

Comment: Is the JSON valid now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need *logo - original - url* this is sufficient

```
struct Eventbrite: Decodable {
    let events: [Event]
}

struct Event: Decodable {
    let logo: Logo
}

struct Logo: Decodable {
    let original: Original // note that the type is not `String`
}

struct Original: Decodable {
    let url: URL
}
```

And print the URLs in all events with

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Eventbrite.self, from: data)
for event in result.events {
    print(event.logo.original.url)
}
```

It seems that you still don't understand the relationship dictionary <-> struct. You are encouraged to learn it

And declare struct members only as optional if you get appropriate error messages.

Comment: This worked- thank you. After about 4 hours of reading Apple documentation & watching tutorials. I understand better now lol! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
struct Logo: Decodable{
    let original: String?
}
```

to

```
struct Logo: Decodable{
    let original: Original?
}
```

Here is full Code

```
import Foundation

struct Eventbrite: Codable {
    let events: [Event]
}

// MARK: Convenience initializers

extension Eventbrite {
    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Eventbrite.self, from: data)
    }
}


struct Event: Codable {
    let name, description: Description
    let start : Start
    let logo: Logo

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, description, logo, start
    }
}

struct Description: Codable {
    let text, html: String
}

struct Start: Codable {
    let timezone, local, utc: String
}

struct Logo: Codable {
    let cropMask: CropMask
    let original: Original
    let id, url, aspectRatio: String
    let edgeColorSet: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case cropMask = "crop_mask"
        case original, id, url
        case aspectRatio = "aspect_ratio"
        case edgeColorSet = "edge_color_set"
    }
}

struct CropMask: Codable {
    let topLeft: TopLeft
    let width, height: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case topLeft = "top_left"
        case width, height
    }
}

struct TopLeft: Codable {
    let x, y: Int
}

struct Original: Codable {
    let url: String
    let width, height: Int
}
```

Comment: Hi, this game me an error - "Cannot get keyed decoding container -- found null value instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Thank you, I am plugging it in now to check. Is it necessary to have all of the structs such as topleft and cropMask? I only needed the image URL to display.

Comment: I don’t understand ? I’m sorry. Write in coding key where?

Comment: see my solution and check  **enum CodingKeys**  that allow you to to set your key as CamelCase , i use Coding Protocol which is Decoding and encoding

Comment: for more info about **Codable**  you can read this https://hackernoon.com/everything-about-codable-in-swift-4-97d0e18a2999

Comment: Ok I understand. So if none of the data I need is in camel case- I only need original, Id, url- can I completely get rid of the enum Coding keys in that case?

Comment: Yes you can Do this

Comment: Ok, that’s what I was confused about, thank you I will check now and hopefully it is correct. Thanks

Comment: Hello friend, does it matter if i use codable or decodable? All of the previous ones i used were decodable

Comment: codable is decodable and encodable  , if you use decodable then you can decode you json to mode only l using Decoder